# SQL Rounding Question

Tags: sql, rounding

I have the following values being returned in a column.. 0.250000 and 13.000000.  I'd like to round the 0.250000 up to 1 and leave the 13 as is.  Any easy way to do this since they both fall within the same column?

Comment: What would 13.01 be rounded to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DBMS probably has a CEILING function. Try that.

Comment: Boourns! You fast typer. I'll vote you up if you vote me up ;)

Answer (score 2):

The ceiling function will work well because you want to round to the nearest whole number.  For more methods on rounding with SQL Server....

[SQL Server Rounding Methods](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-rounding-methods)

Comment: G M - the "nearest whole number" isn't always the next whole number in the sequence.  Sometimes a floor() is necessary, depending on the requirements that were evidently left out from the original post.

Comment: cLFlaVA,

I agree with you.  

In this particular case, this really isn't rounding, it's a form of truncating.  I provided the link for rounding methods in case others stumble across this with an actual rounding question.

Comment: But yes, based on the limited information provided, ceiling would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

select CEILING( columnname ) from tablename